# Difference between @RestController and @RepositoryRestController

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-restcontroller

What is the typical use case **code** that shows the difference between those two annotations - meaning the `@RestController` and the `@RepositoryRestController` - ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the annotation the [`RepositoryRestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryRestController.html) is a way to provide custom controllers that still take advantage of Spring Data REST functionality.

Spring Data REST Reference Guide, [15.6. Overriding Spring Data REST Response Handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers):

> Sometimes you may want to write a custom handler for a specific
> resource. To take advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, message
> converters, exception handling, and more, use the
> @RepositoryRestController annotation instead of a standard Spring MVC
> @Controller or @RestController.

Most importantly the `RepositoryRestController` is aware of the Spring Data REST base path and will be served under this base path.